# Vue form with add more buttons

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to convert a long form to use Vue so that it is more interactive.

As a shortish example I have the following markup.

```
<template>
    <form v-on:submit.prevent action="" method="post">
        <div class="row no-gutter application-section-container">

            <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 application-section-category-sidebar">
                <h3 id="profile" class="application-section-header">Profile</h3>
                <small class="d-block application-section-info">Please fill in your profile details.</small>
                <small class="d-block application-section-requirements"><strong>(All Fields Required)</strong></small>
                <small class="d-block application-section-status"><strong>Incomplete</strong></small> 
            </div>

            <div class="col-12 col-lg-8">
                <div class="application-section" id="application-user-profile">

                <div class="form-row">

                    <div class="col">
                        <label for="first_name">First Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name" autocomplete="given-name" value="" readonly v-model="first_name">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col">
                        <label for="last_name">Last Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" autocomplete="family-name" value="" readonly v-model="last_name">
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <label for="email">Email Address<span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="john.doe@example.com" autocomplete="email" value="" readonly v-model="email">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col">
                        <label for="contact_number">Contact Number<span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <input required type="tel" class="form-control" name="contact_number" id="contact_number" minlength="11" maxlength="14" autocomplete="tel" value="" v-model="contact_number">
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="form-row">

                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        <label for="gender">Gender<span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <select required name="gender" id="gender" class="form-control" v-model="gender">
                            <option v-for="gender in genders" v-bind:key="gender" v-bind:value="gender">{{ gender }}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-12 mb-3">
                        <label for="profile_address_line_1">Street Address<span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" name="profile_address_line_1" id="profile_address_line_1" placeholder="Address, Line 1" value="" v-model="profile_address_line_1">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" name="profile_address_line_2" id="profile_address_line_2" placeholder="Address, Line 2" value="" v-model="profile_address_line_2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" name="profile_address_line_3" id="profile_address_line_3" placeholder="Address, Line 3" value="" v-model="profile_address_line_3">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 mb-3">
                        <label for="profile_town">Town/City<span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="profile_town" id="profile_town" value="" v-model="profile_town">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 mb-3">
                        <label for="profile_county">Region/County<span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="profile_county" id="profile_county" value="" v-model="profile_county"> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 mb-3">
                        <label for="profile_postcode">Postcode<span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="profile_postcode" id="profile_postcode" value="" v-model="profile_postcode">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <label for="profile_country">Country<span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="profile_country" id="profile_country" v-model="profile_country">
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input class="custom-control-input profile_has_disability" type="checkbox" name="profile_has_disability" value="" id="profile_has_disability" v-model="profile_has_disability">
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="profile_has_disability">
                                Do you have any disabilities?
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-12 profile-disabilities-container" v-if="profile_has_disability">
                        <label for="profile_disabilities">Please state your disabilities:</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="profile_disabilities" id="profile_disabilities" rows="4" v-model="profile_disabilities"></textarea>    
                        <small>*This will enable us to make any reasonable adjustments for candidates at interview stage</small>
                    </div>        
                </div>

            </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return{
                'genders': [
                    'Male',
                    'Female',
                    'Other',
                    'Prefer not to say'
                ],
                'first_name': null,
                'last_name': null,
                'email': null,
                'contact_number': null,
                'gender': null,
                'profile_address_line_1': null,
                'profile_address_line_2': null,
                'profile_address_line_3': null,
                'profile_town': null,
                'profile_county': null,
                'profile_postcode': null,
                'profile_country': null,
                'profile_has_disability': null,
                'profile_disabilities': null,
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getProfile();
        },
        methods:{
            getProfile(){
                axios.get('/account/api/profile')
                    .then((response) => {
                        console.log(response.data);   
                        this.first_name = response.data.user.first_name;
                        this.last_name = response.data.user.last_name;
                        this.email = response.data.user.email;
                        this.contact_number = response.data.user.contact_number;
                        this.gender = response.data.user.gender;
                        this.profile_address_line_1 = response.data.user.profile_address_line_1;
                        this.profile_address_line_2 = response.data.user.profile_address_line_2;
                        this.profile_address_line_3 = response.data.user.profile_address_line_3;
                        this.profile_town = response.data.user.town;
                        this.profile_county = response.data.user.county;
                        this.profile_postcode = response.data.user.postcode;
                        this.profile_country = response.data.user.country;
                        this.profile_has_disability = response.data.user.has_disability;
                        this.profile_disabilities = response.data.user.disabilities;
                    }).catch((err) => {
                        console.log(err);
                    });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Currently I am simply just binding variables and that gives me this:

[image]

This works pretty well but later down the form users would be able to add records like education details with an add row button.

In the original version I was just looping through `$user->educationDetails` in the actual Blade file.

In Vue is my best bet just to load these objects into a data property and loop through them with `v-for`?

This would also mean I'd have to return the user as well as a few other related models.

Should it be separated out, or could I just return the data at the same endpoint?

Here is the original form I'm converting:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just try to return data from one of the controllers from Laravel to the vuejs file. Catch the returned data in vuejs file through props and giving it the same variable name with the returned variable name from the controller.

https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html

If you are working the project through using laravel and vue separately. Then, you should try requesting the data from laravel using axios from vue. And just assigning the data back to the variables inside the vue when requested data is received.

https://www.tutsmake.com/laravel-9-vue-js-axios-get-request-tutorial/

I am also just beginner and sorry if I am not giving much help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, when I'm done, I'll share the solution I ended up with.